# AWS DMS - Migrate existing data and replicate on-going changes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I am exploring DMS for migrating RDS Postgres to Aurora database.

Can someone please explain how this migration type works: "Migrate existing data and replicate on-going changes"

Time T1 - So, my application is talking Source database

Time T2 - I use DMS to migrate data from source to target database.

Time T3 - Data migration completes..

Time T4 - I change my application to use target database by changing the endpoint of the database

My question is - Is the above order correct ? What happens to data writes on source DB between Time T3 and T4 ? Does. "replicate on-going changes" , means, it will keep replicating the data from Source to Target till it is not stopped , and will make sure all writes get replicated to Target database ?

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got the gist of it. Overall, DMS is pretty good at migrating changes on the source database over to the target database. As long as the task is active, it will continue to replicate changes based on the rules you provide.

Just make sure you put some alerting on your binlog/wal size. If the task stops for any reason, transaction logs will start to fill up and that can get pretty ugly.